# C# Blazor WebAssembly - how to access device heading

Tags: performance, blazor, geolocation, webassembly, heading

I am currently working on a simple .net8 blazor webassembly (client side rendering) application that needs to change the information on the screen based on the device location and heading. I found interesting nuget package that seems to be working well with the location and is hooking into the JSRuntime to get the Geolocation API calls and receive the information about the device location and orientation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

The location information is being sent properly but heading is not provided.
Looking at the API specification:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

The heading is only available when the device is in motion (I assume it is then estimated based on the lat and long changes rather then actually obtained from the device sensors). The problem is, the no matter how much I move the speed and heading data is not available.

Any ideas how to get the device heading data in Chrome or any other browser? Ideally also when the device is not moving.

Many thanks for help in advance.

Used the dedicated nuget package, for Blazor:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates/heading

Obtained proper updates for lat and long, but no data is available for speed and heading.